# Problem with ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock and jQuery in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: asp.net, jquery, plugins, scriptmanager, registerclientscriptblock

I want to use jGrowl plugin for jQuery (http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html#samples) to display some messages on a page. To do this, I call the ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock method like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
   "$.jGrowl('" + message + "');", true);
```

The code works perfect in Firefox/Chrome/Safari. However in Internet Explorer I don't see the notification and I don't get any Javascript error.

I work under Windows 7 and I have Internet Explorer 8 Beta (version 8.0.7000.0) and I have the same "bug" under Compatibility Mode.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem occurs because IE8 expects all the DOM elements to be loaded before modifications to the DOM can be made. I was able to duplicate the problem you described with jGrowl.

To fix it, I just modified your script so that the call to jGrowl happens once the document is ready. Here's the updated code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), 
     Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
     "$(function(){$.jGrowl('" + message + "');});", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried you fix, but it's still not working. Could be because of the fact I have an update panel on the page?

Comment: I did test this code with an update panel and it worked fine. Did you actually copy/paste the code above? Are you getting any javascript errors in the browser?

Comment: If after doing this, you still have a problem, you may need to updgrade to the final version of IE8 instead of the Beta.

Answer (score 2):

add `<form runat="server" id="form1">` to page. It will work...

Answer (score 0):

If not wrong, I think you have to add this in the client side page.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" id="forModalPopUp">
    var prm =  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    }
    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
    }
</script>
```

For more details, take a look at [this](http://oysterleelife.blogspot.com/2012/05/scripmanager-error-in-updatepanel.html).