# JQuery not working

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to implement JQuery in my web page but i am not been able to implement it successfully.

I have a master page

where i added one script for menu bar that is already using jquery hosted by Google

This is coded in master page itself

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now i want to implement a Jquery to set the css visibility property to true or false.
into my `content page` of same master page.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){  
                $("#lnkAddMore").click(function(){
                 alert();
                  }
                  );
            });
        </script>
```

This html control is under my `UpdatePanel`. 
I dont know why it is not working ?
I am using this control under UpdatePanel.

```
<input type="button" id="lnkAddMore" value="Add More" />
```

> I tried to use it outside my update
>   panel it is running successfully but
>   not in UpdatePanel

**I think there is a problem using it with an UpdatePanel**

> **HERE IS MY PAGE SOURCE**

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 


    <link href="../../Css/Domain.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $("#lnkAddMore").click(function(){alert();$('#h').hide(100);});
            $('#h').show(100);
        });
    </script> 


       <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="divDomain" runat="server">
<asp:gridview/>
                <div style="text-align:right;">
                    <input type="button" id="lnkAddMore" value="Add More" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: where are the definitions of ddmenu_open and ddmenu_timer functions?

Comment: @curtisk: their defination are within the same script tag. I just removed it here to make code more readable. That part of JQuery is running fine

Comment: Are you trying to add the click event to an element that was loaded dynamically by the update panel?

Comment: @ROMAN No i m not adding that element dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used two approaches with jQuery and UpdatePanels.

The first is this:
[jQuery $(document).ready and UpdatePanels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels/256253#256253)

The other approach I found on Rick Strahl's blog (http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/154797.aspx) Which is to do something like this in the code behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "alertScript", 
    @" $(document).ready(function(){  
            $("#lnkAddMore").click(function(){
             alert();
              }
              );
        });", true);
```

Check this out for another example: [Problem with ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock and jQuery in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844004/problem-with-scriptmanager-registerclientscriptblock-and-jquery-in-internet-explo/844714#844714)

Also have a look at jQuery's [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)  event subscriber.

Answer (score 4):

Do you really have nested `<script>` tags or was it a typo?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<script type="text/javascript">
```

If that's not a typo, then that's probably the issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('#ddmenu > li').bind('mouseover', ddmenu_open)
        $('#ddmenu > li').bind('mouseout',  ddmenu_timer)
    });

    $(document).bind('click', ddmenu_close); // do you really want to close on any click?
</script>
```

Comment: I used it like this <script></script>  <script></script>

Comment: In your code above you have a <script> tag inside of another <script> tag, which will cause your js to throw an exception and your click event will not be bound

Answer (score 1):

Check that the ID of your button isn't actually getting changed to something like

```
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkAddMore
```

since it's residing in a content placeholder for the master page.

If it is, you'd have to adjust your JQuery.

Comment: @Lester No its name is not changing. I have taken button as an HTML control

Comment: is it there some other way to call JQuery when using with UpdatePanel

Comment: This is being displayed in source. ID is same there            <div style="text-align:right;"> 
                        <input type="button" id="lnkAddMore" value="Add More" /> 
                        </div>

Answer (score 0):

When you're loading code in under an UpdatePanel, try not wrapping it in `$(document).ready();`. Ready isn't fired on `document` for AJAX events.

Comment: I edited my page code to <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $("#lnkAddMore").click(function(){alert();});
    </script> . But still it is not working