# $(document.body).append() doesn't seem to work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, append, document-body

I am redirecting my user to my default.aspx when his session expires and default page is referenced under a master page. I show a notification like twitter stating `Session Expired` what happens is it works fine in firefox and google chrome but not in IE. I get `Internet Explorer cannot open site-http://localhost:1335/order/Default.aspx?Sid=1 Operation aborted`

I googled this and found that `$(document.body).append()` before the body tag was the problem if i move the script to my bottom of my page my notification doesn't work in any browser.

Here is my master page,

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="Javascript/Jquery1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function topBar(message) {
            $("#alertmsg").remove();
            var $alertdiv = $('<div id = "alertmsg"/>');
            $alertdiv.text(message);
            $alertdiv.bind('click', function() {
                $(this).slideUp(200);
            });
            $(document.body).append($alertdiv);
            $("#alertmsg").slideDown("slow");
            setTimeout(function() { $alertdiv.slideUp(200); }, 5000);
        }
    </script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
```

and my topbar function is called in my default.aspx page,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int64 id = GetId(Request.RawUrl.ToString());
  if (id == 1)
  {
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, this.GetType(), "json", "topBar('Session Expired');", true);
  }
}
```

Comment: When is the `topBar` function called?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP.NET. Can you look at the generated page source and see where the function is actually called? It may be the case that it's being called too early, i.e. before the body is parsed.

Comment: @casablanca charlie's answer worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find the place where `topBar` is called, but if I call it from `$(document).ready()` it worked like a charm in my IE8:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function topBar(message) { 
        $("#alertmsg").remove(); 
        var $alertdiv = $('<div id = "alertmsg"/>'); 
        $alertdiv.text(message); 
        $alertdiv.bind('click', function() { 
            $(this).slideUp(200); 
        }); 
        $(document.body).append($alertdiv); 
        $("#alertmsg").slideDown("slow"); 
        setTimeout(function() { $alertdiv.slideUp(200); }, 5000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        topBar("Hello world!");
    });
</script>
```

You could also use `$(window).load()` if you have graphics and/or other heavy elements that needs to be loaded before `topBar()` is called:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    topBar("Hello world!");
});
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

---

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510892/jquery-not-working/2511968#2511968) can be of some help? Basically you could do something like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "json",  
    @"$(document).ready(function(){   
             topBar("Hello world!");
             }); 
        });", true);
```

Check out the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510892/jquery-not-working/2511968#2511968) in the link because he gives a couple of alternatives

Comment: I answered before the edit was made about where the function was called, as I was just now researched to be able to update my answer I get a down-vote without any explanation. I suppose It doesn't answer the question as it is put now, but with the information I was given at the time, I think it is a valid answer.

Comment: i ve edited the question 4 mins before you posted this answer

Comment: Maybe my typing isn't the fastest and I needed to test the result? Anyhow, no hard feelings. I've updated my answer, hope it gets you going.

Comment: your answer worked. Sorry for down voting initially because i knew the answer which was given by you before the update. Anyhow thanks man no hard feelings.